# Java, limit the BufferedReader reading time

Tags: java, timeout, max, bufferedreader, execution-time

I have written this very classic piece of code to read the content of an URL.

```
// Prepares the connection
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

// Reads the data
StringBuilder data;
String inputLine;
try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
    data = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        data.append(inputLine);
    }
}

// Returns the read data
return data.toString();
```

But sometimes, the url I'm reading contains too much data, or the client connection is too slow, or whatever... and so the reading takes too much time.

Is there a way to specify to the BufferedReader (or to the InputStreamReader, or maybe to the URLConnection?) a "max-reading-time"? Ideally it will throw a TimeoutException after "the max-reading-time" is reach.

I made some research, but all I could find was limitation on the size of the data received, not on the execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `URLConnection.setReadTimeout()` before starting to read. If the timeout expires, a `SocketTimeoutException` will be thrown.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know how that is implemented?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis With `Socket.setSoTimeout(),` of course, in the case of network URLs. Does nothing for other URLs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Certainly, using either `SO_RCVTIMEO` or `select()` depending on the platform.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that :D Thanks anyway!